# IOS Development making viewcells clickable

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm just beginning IOS development and am wondering if anybody could help me figure out how to get the cell details that are being clicked.

I have a cell like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ICICell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic)IBOutlet ICICell *myCell;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myGallery;


@end
```

in the view controller I am populating the cells like this:

```
    -(UICollectionViewCell * ) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    ICICell * aCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"myCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    aCell.myLabel.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];

    UIImage *img;
    long row = [indexPath row];
    img = [UIImage imageNamed:self.iciImages[row]];

    aCell.myGallery.image = img;

    return aCell;
}
```

I have found the didDeselectItemAtIndexPath method, but is there a method didSelectItemAtIndexPath?

I am trying to get the label text for a selected cell.  Bit confused why there is a didDeselect and no didSelect?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple answer : Yes, the method you are looking for exists. Did you search it? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no didSelect method"? There is one.

Comment: I must admit I only did a very quick search and didn't find it.  I think the fact that XCode didn't suggest it in code completion I made a poor assumption.  Thanks - I've found it now.

Comment: This is now the first link that comes up when you google "clickable UICollectionViewCell", funny how stack works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linda Keating,

> There are both methods available as you are expecting..have a reference from below

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    /* Here you can do any code for Selected item at indexpath.*/
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Of course You can navigate into Detail Screen of Collection View cell.

Just use `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     VIPRoomDetailController *enterIntoRoomDetail = [[VIPRoomDetailController alloc]initWithNibName:@"VIPRoomDetailController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:enterIntoRoomDetail animated:YES];


}
```

Also Import Detail controller in your collection View class In my case it is `VIPRoomDetailController`